# Changing the order of TreeSet elements to customized output

Tags: java, sorting, treeset

I know that TreeSet stores objects in a sorted manner. But is there a way that i can customize the order?

For example if i have a treeSet:

```
 TreeSet t1 = new TreeSet();
    t1.add("c");
    t1.add("d");
    t1.add("a");
```

And now if i iterate over it>

```
 Iterator it1 =t1.iterator();

    while(it1.hasNext()){
      Object o1 = it1.next();
      System.out.println(o1);
    }
```

i will always get the order as: `a>c>d`, however i want it to return the order the same as i added the elements in it i.e `c>d>a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention about being bound to use TreeSet, something like this comes to my mind:

```
 Set<String> result = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        return returnCode(arg0).compareTo(returnCode(arg1));
    }
 });
```

where:

```
private Integer returnCode(String p){
        int code = 0;
        String id = p.toLowerCase();
        if ("a".equalsIgnoreCase(id)) code = 3;
        else if ("b".equalsIgnoreCase(id)) code = 2;
        else if ("c".equalsIgnoreCase(id)) code = 1;
        //etc
        return new Integer(code);
 }
```

So basically you are implementing your own comparator which is nothing but assigning certain integer values to the inserted String (which i assume you know already).

NOTE: this solution will not work, incase you do not catch the option in your returnCode() method. I assume you already know the data that is being fed to the TreeSet.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) for it,

`TreeSet` sorts the element, and for string it sorts based on natural order( this is how its comparator is implemented), If you want to manage the insertion order then you need to user `LinkedHashSet`

and if you don't need the uniquness (feature of set) then go for `List`

Comment: but if i implement my own comparator and override the original one, i think it will work. Haven't seen LinkedHashSet, let me check, thank you for the answer.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is designed explicitly for this purpose and will be faster. Besides, the kind of `Comparator` you would need to keep track of the order of insertion would have to be stateful, which is not a good idea for something that is just meant to be a functor.  Go with `LinkedHashSet`, @Jigar is right.

Comment: @sparc_spread, thanks actually the treeSet is already there part of a library. And now if i go for LInkedHashSet, i will have to modify the extenral library as a whole :( but i will try, thank you

Comment: Hello Thankyou for the answer, although i managed to do it using my own comparator because i was bound to use TreeSet only in my requirement. Thank you

Comment: How did you implement comparator , did you manage to do it by millis/nanos of insertion or something ?

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` is as much a part of the JDK as `TreeSet`, unless you are using a very old version of Java (pre-2002), in which case you should upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more easy:

```
TreeSet treeSetObj = new TreeSet(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a good answer. It's my first one.

```
import java.util.*;
class M
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TreeSet<String> t=new TreeSet<>(new MyComparator());

    t.add("c");
    t.add("d");
    t.add("a");

    System.out.println(t);//[c,d,a] not [a,c,d] ....your answer

 }
 }

class MyComparator implements Comparator
{
public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
{
    String i1=(String)o1;
    String i2=(String)o2;
    return +1; //Store elements as they come
}
```

}

What basically +1 does store the elements in the order in which they come.

Always remember
if I write return +1 it means to store the elements in the order in which they come.
if I write return -1 it means to store the elements in reverse order in which they come.